# Android Studio 1.4 not showing Log.d() for selected application

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I stumbled upon a strange issue/bug with A.Studio 1.4

While running my app I have by default the selection in logcat:
[image]
All but one Log.d() of my app actually shows here as they should, the only one Log.D that appears is inside onCreate...

When i Select "No Filter":
[image]
All other Log.d() appear but among a "sea" of unnecessary log information every second. So i have to use the searchbox..

Previously all Log.d was shown only for the selected application which made it easy to see and find, now it is impossible among all other data. Any suggestion of how to fix that and see only error exceptions and debug info?

Comment: Type something into the search field that identifies your messages, such as a unique bit of your application ID. For example, I use `commonsware`.

Comment: Yes, I add that but yet still it does not appear in "show only selected application" Can that be due to the fact that some of the Log.d's have an empty tag.

Comment: hehe, I had the same problem today(with `Log.e` inside `onCreateLoader` before `new CursorLoader()`) ...  which cost me 1h of debugging :) ... the ContentProvider logged the query but Log.e was not shown..

Comment: "I add that but yet still it does not appear in "show only selected application"" -- oh, sure. That's been broken for quite some time. It's certainly not new to 1.4. I gave up on the "selected application" filter as being a lost cause.

Comment: The integrated logcat in Studio is basically magic black box that may or may not work randomly. For actually precise logs i'd recommend opening Android Monitor from I think Tools menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create your own filter (inside `Edit Filter Configuration`). You can set package name of your application there. After that you'll see all your `Log` messages.

Answer (score 0):

I see this if some log entries have tags and some don't. Try adding the same tag to all related entries. You'll also then be able to filter based on that tag. Create a filter by selecting Edit Filter Configuration from the filter dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

I just update to Android Studio 1.5 Preview. and works!